# Bluetooth is not disabled

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to disable the Bluetooth from my code but it remains enabled and no errors are thrown.
Here is my code.

```
if (m_BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
    m_BluetoothAdapter.disable();
}
if (m_BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() == false){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BLUETOOTH is being disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the only code in my app for testing.
I also put permission for Bluetooth and Bluetooth_admin.
Neither Eclipse nor mobile gives any error but BT remains enable.
Pl point me what I am doing wrong.
Regards

Update :
Well, I discovered that if I run this app 1st time, BT remains enable.
But if I run app again (2nd time), BT is disabled.
I am not sure why BT is disabled only on the 2nd run and not first time.
Any ideas?

Comment: How you initialised adapter?

Comment: BluetoothAdapter m_BluetoothAdapter = null; // Local Bluetooth adapter
    m_BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `disable()` method makes an asynchronous call so for this reason your code seems not working.

In other words it takes some time when bluetooth will be disabled. In this case you should use BroadcastReceiver with **`BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED`** intent-filter and listen for state changes and then make proper actions.

Available states **`STATE_ON`**  **`STATE_TURNING_OFF`** and **`STATE_OFF`**

Also look what says docs:

> true to indicate adapter shutdown has begun, or false on immediate
>   error

Comment: Taking time is fine but I waited for long to see if BT is disabled or not. But BT remains enabled even after 5 mins.

Comment: @madiyamadiya you are testing it on emulator or real device?

Comment: Emulator does not support Bluetooth and wifi. I am testing on real device. WiFi works fine but Bluetooth is not getting disabled. Pl note that there is no problem in enabling the same.

Comment: @madiyamadiya interesting and if you'll enable/disable it manually it works i assume?

Comment: @madiyamadiya so problem is in your code. hardware works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://code.google.com/p/backport-android-bluetooth/) library , its easy to use and more friendly 
also try with below code

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
}
```

Comment: I am using exact same code but it fails. Not sure about the library you suggested. Since I am fairly new here, would stick to the standard ones. But anyway, Thanks.